# Set product retail price programmatically

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, price

How can I set the Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price of programmatically added products? I have tryied to use `$product->setRetailPrice()` but the price didn't change, it is blank. How to change it or what class method to use?

The product is created with: `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referring to the product special price.
In this case you should do:

```
$product->setSpecialPrice(99.99);
```

or

```
$product->setData('special_price', 99.99);
```

As a general case, in order to set an attribute do this:

```
$product->setData('attribute_code_here', 'value_here');
//or
$product->setAttributeCodeHere('value_here');
```

**[EDIT]**

For `Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price` the code is `msrp`.
So use

```
$product->setData('msrp', 99.99);
//or
$product->setMsrp(99.99);
```

If you don't know the attribute code, look it up by label in `Catalog->Attributes->Manage attributes` and you should see the code also.

Comment: No. Not special price. But `Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price`. What attribute code does it have?

Comment: @SpartakusMd. See my update